# Windows CLI tool to remove a specified line from a section within an `ini` file

Tags: windows, gratis, command-line, text-processing, text-search

Please recommend a gratis Windows CLI tool that allows one to remove a specified line from a section within an `ini` file.

For example, let's say you have the following `ini` file:

```
[settings]
height=100
width=200
add="+"
subtract="-"
multiply="*"
divide="/"

[operators]
add="+"
subtract="-"
multiply="*"
divide="/"
```

and you want to remove the line `subtract="-"` from the `[operators]` section **(only)**, regardless of the value to which `subtract` is assigned.

So I would like a CLI tool where I can specify something like:
`tool.exe foo.ini -remove subtract in operators`
to remove that line.

Comment: That kind of things are usually done with PowerShell or Cygwin commands, or with advanced text editors that support find-and-replace with regular expressions, so if you have those available you could ask the same question in superuser.com

Comment: @golimar is correct, `type in.ini | findstr /V 'subtract="' > out.ini` would do the trick in cmd.exe while `Get-Content in.ini | Select-String -NotMatch -Pattern "^subtract=" > out.ini` is the PowerShell equivalent.

Comment: Why not post that as an answer?